# Unable to drag & drop the box in selenium

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop

I am trying to apply drag & drop function.Neither it gives me error nor it is working. The XPath of the box(which i need to drag&drop) is correct and i am able to click on it. Please suggest
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tPJG.png)

Comment: Must to provide HTML and Trial code

Answer (score 0):

First, you question have no Html, I am giving an answer which is generic

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 driver.get(URL you want to hit);

 //Element which needs to drag.         
 WebElement FromElem=driver.findElement("Locator"));

 //Element on which need to drop.       
 WebElement ToElem=driver.findElement("Locator"));  

 //Using Action class for drag and drop.        
 Actions act=new Actions(driver);   

 //Dragged and dropped.     
 act.dragAndDrop(FromElem, ToElem).build().perform();   

}
```